# How to get category name of `animal` object?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django ORM.

```
class AnimalFile(models.Model):
    filepath = models.FileField(upload_to="f")

class Food(models.Model):
    main = models.ForeignKey(AnimalFile)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food)
```

views:

```
def single_animal(request,id):
    animal = AniamalFile.objects.get(id=id)
```

How to get category name of `animal` object? I need display it in template also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, you can do:

```
def single_animal(request,id):
    animal = AniamalFile.objects.get(id=id)

    animal_category=None
    categories = Category.objects.filter(food__main=animal)
    if categories:
        animal_category = categories[0]
```

You can pass this as a context variable, and access it as `{{animal_category}}`

Or if you want to show all the categories, just send `categories` in the context and in the template:

```
{% for cat in categories %}{{cat.name}} {% endfor %}
```

Alternatively,

```
def single_animal(request,id):
    animal = AniamalFile.objects.get(id=id)

    animal_category=None
    foodset = animal.food_set.all()

    categories = Category.objects.filter(food__in=foodset)
```

Comment: there are better approaches. Go for it :)